# Connect GIT project with Eclipse Force.com project

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide, git, version-control

I'm using Eclipse MARS v2 and Force.com IDE v36. I am trying to get Eclipse connected to a GIT project I just cloned down to a local directory on my drive: `My Computer >> My Documents >> GitHub >> Repo >> My Project`

I need to create my Force.com project and point to the above directory where my GIT repo is located. Then I need to connect that Force.com project to my development sandbox.

I haven't been able to open or import the GIT project directory into a Force.com project. I've been searching on how to do this, but can't seem to find the right information on to accomplish this. The import option does not give me a Force.com project option. Using open file option does not work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you've already cloned the repository, you can proceed as follows. Click on File > Import > Git / Projects from Git > Existing Local Repository > Add... (add your repo's local directory) > Import as General Project > Type a project name > Finish. Then, right-click on the project, choose Force.com > Add Force.com nature. After that, right-click on the project, choose Properties > Force.com, and enter your credentials. Click no when prompted to refresh from the server (you'll want to use Synchronize instead). Finally, right-click the project, choose Force.com > Synchronize with server, and make any synchronization deployments that you need.

Alternatively, if your repo already contains a .project file for Eclipse, you can go the other direction: click on File > Import... > General / Existing projects into workspace > Select the root folder for the repo > Select the project to import > Finish. From there, you can then set your Force.com credentials and synchronize, as above.

Comment: This was a great answer as this wasn't obvious to me the first time I had to do this. If you're still thinking about a book idea, 'Practical Step-By-Step for setting up a CI/CD environment for Enterprise Developers' with examples in DX, Eclipse and other dev envs.  Use cases would include one-man bands, small teams, larger teams.  Seems like ISVs know how to do this